# Sencha Touch 2 modifying properties of a xtype through controller?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm still a noobie in Sencha touch 2.  So the problem i have here is im using this date-time-picker made by someone else. I just want to be able to modify a property of the date-time-picker, but it doesnt have a usual get or set methods.

```
                        {
                            xtype: 'datetimepickerfield',
                            flex: 1,
                            id: 'approxBedtime',
                            action:'bedtime',
                            width: 110,
                            //placeHolder: '9:00 PM',
                            value: new Date('','','',22,0),
                            dateTimeFormat: 'h:i:A',
                            picker: {
                                useTitles: true,
                                minuteInterval: 1,
                                ampm: true,
                                slotOrder: ['hour', 'minute', 'ampm'],
                            },
                        },
```

This is in my view, and i want to modify the ampm with javascript in a controller, or intialize function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

in controller (eg. if you defined in ref section: 'dateTimePicker': '#mypicker')

```
var datetimepicker = this.getDateTimePicker();
var picker = datetimepicker.getPicker();
picker.setAmpm(true);
```

Cheers, Oleg